# How to split by Word Boundary or a Number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a word-filter that searches for words using this regex:

```
/\b[a-zA-Z-]+\b/
```

Searching the word: "hello".

- Case 1: "Hello there" = true
- Case 2: "Hello0 there" = false
- Case 3: "Hello_there" = false
- Case 4: "Hello-there" = false
- Case 5: "4Hello there" = false

How can I setup the Word Boundaries to also find words that start/end with a number, underscore, hyphen or any other character other than a letter?

Comment: Do you mean `/(?<![^\W\d])[a-zA-Z]+(?![^\W\d])/`?

Comment: Man that was fast. Looks like that's working, and to extend it to include underscores - I can use: `/(?<![^\W\d_])[a-zA-Z]+(?![^\W\d_])/` ?

Comment: Well, the `[^\W\d_]` is a pattern that matches all the letters that `\w` matches. So, it is basically `[a-zA-Z]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/(?<![^\W\d])[a-zA-Z]+(?![^\W\d])/
```

The `(?<![^\W\d])` negative lookbehind matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a char other than a non-word and a digit char, i.e. there must be either start of string or a word char but a digit.

The `(?![^\W\d])` negative lookahead matches a location that is not immediately followed with a char other than a non-word and a digit char, i.e. there must be either end of string or a word char other than a digit.

Comment: This looks perfect, I've just tested it on rubular.com - how would you include underscores? As they're not part of the \W match.

Comment: @Kobius The thing is, if you add `_` to the character classes, you cancel the word boundary behavior. `(?<![^\W\d_])[a-zA-Z]+(?![^\W\d_])` = `[a-zA-Z]+` (as `[^\W\d_]` = `[a-zA-Z]`, it matches a letter). Same effect when you write `\b\w+\b` = `\w+`.

Comment: that makes sense, essentially I'm hoping to also use this as part of a class that uses filenames. Filenames are restricted to only numbers, letters and underscores so I'm not sure the best way to check for words such as "hello" when it's part of a string such as "314hello_there".